# For a given function g(n), Why is Θ (g(n)) the set of functions?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

In the Introduction to algorithms book, the definition of Θ(g(n)) is given by:

Θ(g(n)) = { f(n): there exist positive constants c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, and n<sub>0</sub> such that 0 <= c<sub>1</sub>*g(n) <= f(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>g(n) for all n>=n<sub>0</sub> }

I understand that f(n) can always be sandwiched between c<sub>1</sub>g(n) and c<sub>2</sub>g(n) for sufficiently large n when n<sub>0</sub> >= 0.

I am not able to understand why Θ(g(n)) is a set of functions of f(n). Per my understanding f(n) is just one function between c<sub>1</sub>g(n) and c<sub>2</sub>g(n) . If Θ(g(n)) is a set of functions of f(n) then does that mean that there could be more than one functions f(n)? like   Θ(g(n)) = { f(n<sub>1</sub>), f(n<sub>2</sub>), f(<sub>n2</sub>),... , f(<sub>n</sub>) } all of the functions f(n) having their own constants c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>0</sub> .

Comment: Try to prove that `f(x) = 5n²+3n+1` is contained in `Θ(n²)` (i.e. can be sandwiched in between some two `c n²`). In fact, all quadratic polynoms with arbitrary coefficients are.

Comment: @Bergi ... and even non-polynomial functions like `(x+sin(x))²`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be multiple functions having their own constants. For instance,
Θ(n) contains n, 2n, 3n, 4n, ... for instance where for kn you could just use n0 = 0 and c1=c2=k.